# Divs in my webpage will not span 100% width of page

Tags: css, width, display

[image]

As you can see, my header and footers do not span the entire page, unlike my row in the center....that does(indicated by the red) my style sheet if needed is this.

```
   html,body{
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;

   }

   #blogheader{

      background-color: green;
      height: 57%;
      margin: 0px;


   }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!, I have been stuck on this for about an hour now. I have no clue why this is happening. I am using bootstrap. But the only row/col combo I have is in the center where the three icons are.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Most of the time when I see this issue it's due to invalid HTML like a div that isn't closed properly. But without a complete code snippet I can't tell you the reason. Does your HTML validate?

Also what are your widths set at for the spring, angular and bootstrap divs?

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are using Bootstrap.

I can reproduce the error which seems to be be because the 'blogheader in not in a `.row` wrapper.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VaBNVw)

**Without `.row`** *view @ fullscreen*

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #blogheader {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div id="blogheader"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**With `.row`** *view @ fullscreen*

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  .container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #blogheader {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
  }

.col-sm-4 {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="blogheader"></div>
     </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
html, body {
    height:100px;
    width:100vw;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!